# Why are haiku usually of 17 syllables?

Tags: poetry, history-of-literature

One of the characteristics of Haiku is that the poems are usually of 17 syllables (5-7-5). Exceptions exist, of course, but 17 is the norm.

Why 17? How did the originators of Haiku come to settle on 17? How does it contribute to a haiku's aesthetics?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Before diving into the history of haiku, there's a precursor step. The Japanese language is broken up into symbols that are what we'd typically write in English as digraphs. Most sounds in Japanese consists of a consonant and a vowel combined. To illustrate this, have a haiku:

> ふ る い け や
>   (*fu ru i ke ya*)
>   か わ ず と び こ む
>   (*ka wa zu to bi ko mu*)
>   み ず の お と
>   (*mi zu no o to*)

5 symbols, 7 symbols, 5 symbols. So when we talk about "syllables," this meant something much more specific in Japanese. And this [happened to be something of importance to Japanese poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_%28Japanese_prosody%29). Of course, this haiku is easier to read if we split it up by words:

> ふる　いけ　や / かわず　とびこむ / みず　の　おと
>   furu ike ya / kawazu tobikomu / mizu no oto
>   Ah, the ancient pond / as a  frog takes the plunge / the sound of water.

This all is a slight simplification, though. Japanese has digraphs, like きょ, which we write as trigraphs in English: kyo, as in Kyoto. But these still count as one phonetic unit (called "*on*" in Japanese), and that's what notation like "5-7-5" counts. (Haiku tends to be written with kanji, anyway, which changes the raw symbol count. But writing it like I did above serves to show clearly where the *on* are.)

---

With the poetic basis for understanding the structure of the haiku out of the way, let's talk history.

The origins of haiku lie in religious practices, [Shinto and Buddhist alike](http://www.webexhibits.org/poetry/explore_famous_haiku_background.html), as well as [general poetic practices and culture](http://afe.easia.columbia.edu/special/japan_600ce_waka.htm). Songs frequently followed a form called *waka*. This form essentially boiled down to a combination of two other forms: *choka*, which follows 5-7-5-7...5-7-7, and *sedoka*, which follows 5-7-7-5-7-7. This precursor to haiku was just a culturally ingrained pattern - not unlike [the four chord song](https://youtu.be/5pidokakU4I?t=22s) [language warning]. It's just a shared recognizable pattern for music and poetry. And many forms for poetry diverged from there.

The form called *tanka* is a specific form of *waka*, and is so frequently used interchangeably that it has muddied the meaning of *waka*. However, the *tanka* form is a refinement and restriction on the general pattern of *waka*: it follows the form 5-7-5-7-7 specifically. This form is often considered the precursor to what we now call haiku.

Many poets laid their hands on shaping this form in between *tanka* and haiku. Enumerating them all is beyond the scope of this answer. Significant contributors were Matsunaga Teitoku, a wandering poet who wrote a plethora of prose and poetry, and Issa, who wrote often on the state of Japanese society.

But the direct precursor to haiku is [Masaoka Shiki](http://terebess.hu/english/haiku/shiki.html), who took the form that had evolved over time, and focused in on 5-7-5. He *is* the person who gave it the name "haiku," largely under the banner of tanka reform. He wrote well over 25,000 haiku. It is largely the popularization of Shiki's writings in Japan that led to the prominence of the form elsewhere in the world. His commentary presented it as a simpler, cleaner aesthetic - its compressed nature, he wrote, could sketch life and reality much more easily than any more complex form could. This is a strong appeal to [principles in Japanese culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabi-sabi), and is the ultimate aesthetic choice backing haiku.

It was then spread through popular poets and poetry to English-speaking countries - except instead of Japanese phonetic units, they naturally counted in English syllables. The popularization of haiku spread from there into the 1950s, giving us the form we know it in today.

Comment: Heh, "have a haiku" should be "have *the* haiku", considering how famous that particular haiku is.

Comment: My Penguin Book of Zen Poetry https://www.abebooks.co.uk/9780140585995/Penguin-Book-Zen-Poetry-Poets-0140585990/plp translates that Basho as 'Old pond, / leap-splash - / a frog. The book is jointly translated by a Japanese scholar and an American poet. I've always enjoyed the pared down character of their versions.

Comment: @Spagirl that's odd, since it reversed the order of appearance of the frog and the splash. But I suppose it's closer to the compressed nature mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Spagirl Interesting. The last line in the poem, "みずのおと," doesn't actually mean "a frog." It means "water's sound." So I think it's possible that the translator is changing things up a bit for simplicity's sake. That's okay with me, but I think I'll stick with the more direct translation for this answer.

Comment: @Emrakul I didn't mean to suggest changing your answer, only to note that translation can vary and each has its own qualities. Here 'leap-splash' makes the frog's 'taking the plunge' inseparable from 'the sound of water', and as a consequence the order changes.

Comment: @Spagirl Oh! I understand. Yeah, I'd agree, that's certainly an interesting translation difference.

Comment: @muru Since the sound is the intimation of the presence of the frog, perhaps in reality frog and sound are simultaneous, it's the artificiality of writing it down that imposes an order

Comment: @Spagirl that is possible. I don't know much Japanese grammar, but 「かわずとびこむ」could be an adjective clause of 「水の音」, so instead of "an old pond, a frog jumps, sound of the water", it would be "an old pond, and the sound of water that a frog jumped into", which would make the other translation more suitable.

Comment: @muru I've no Japanese at all! It has been interesting to learn more about a poem i've always loved, and to consider the challenge for translators to be truthful tithe text but also to the culture and poetic aesthetics of both languages.

Comment: I've never understood why English haiku exist. There's so much less structure, and it gets taught to students as "look, 17 syllables". It comes across as "the cheapest way to get credit for a poem" and that's all.

Comment: @JoshuaEngel indeed what reminded of Haiku just know was the haiku in *You Only Live Twice*, and iirc, the Japanese guy who hears it says that the syllable count doesn't fit.

Comment: The problem I have with English haiku's is that Japanese Ons aren't syllables. This is because Ons can just as much serve to modify the previous On as they can actually be pronounced. Example: Tokyo, given all it's Ons, should be written Toukyou, but isn't due to them not being pronounced(yet still being counted in a haiku).

Comment: @Tirous but it *is* written that way in kana (there are 5 kana in Tokyo).

Comment: Yes, there are five Kana in 'Toukyou', those being とうきょう, however haikus count On, not Kana, and ょ doesn't count towards the number of On, as it merely exists to modify き、tuning it's 'Ki' into a 'Kyo'; thus 'to-kyo' is 4 On, not 5.

Comment: Also, Tokyo can be pronounced 'to-kee-yo' or 'to-kyo', meaning unlike Japanese it's On count(if you count with syllables) can be variable, thus scientifically proving that the idea of an English haiku is stupid. ;D

Comment: @Tirous: But there's no such thing as an English On. Syllables are as close as we can get.